# How to populate a collection based on existing columns with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two existing tables that have a property (`someField` in the example code).

What I want to do: Fill the collection `Foo.bars` with all `Bar` entities that have the same `someField` value as the `Foo` entity I'm loading.

I don't want to create an extra join table since I don't want to update the relation explicitly.

How do I realize this with annotations on the entities and/or their fields?

Some clarifications:

1. The two `someField` columns are modified independently.
2. There is no unique key constraint on either of the two columns (that's why I added the `@ManyToMany`).
3. I don't need a foreign key relation or any cascading.
4. The columns should not be updated if the collection is modified. I want hibernate to only populate the collection when loading the `Foo` entity.
5. I tried using `@JoinFormula` without any `@XtoY` relation and couldn't get it to work.
6. The relation is only modeled from one side since I don't ever care for the `Foo`s if I have a `Bar` instance.

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.3 which uses Hibernate 5.4.15

```java
@Entity
public class Foo{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int someField;

  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Bar> bars;

}

@Entity
public class Bar{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int someField;

}
```

#### Update 22.06.2020

Since I fail to express my use case I created a minimal [github project](https://github.com/Trinova/arbitrary-join).

The only two ways I found to implement the required behaviour was:

1. Implement explicit controller logic which loads the associated `Bar` instances manually.
2. Implement an AspectJ aspect which attaches to the `FooRepository` load methods which manually fetches the associated `Bar` instances.

Both "fell wrong" since I thought this falls in the scope of hibernate and it creates a lot of additional db queries.

Comment: Is 'someField' unique in the tables, i.e., is there a unique constraint on the columns?

Comment: Did you try to use [@Where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where)?

Comment: And also, do the tables have foreign key constraints in the schema, or do they just sometimes happen to be equal?

Answer (score 1):

So first off, I don't understand why you'd use `@ManyToMany` because that is for n-to-n relationships and yours doesn't look like that.

You can model parent-child relationships in two ways, the most efficient one is the ManyToOne mapping, where the child manages the foreign key to the parent:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int someField;

}

@Entity
public class Child {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int someField;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(
    name = "someField",
    referencedColumnName = "someField",
    unique = false,
    updateable = false,
    insertable = false)
  private Parent parent;

}
```

You can use JPQL/Criteria Queries to fetch everything you need.

Read more about [ManyToOne associations](https://vladmihalcea.com/manytoone-jpa-hibernate/). And here [some more](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/).

See the [@JoinColumn docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) for the attributes like 'unique', etc.

And if you insist on doing it the other way around, that'll work too:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int someField;

  @OneToMany(
    // cascade = What operations do you want to cascade? Who is the owner of the relationship?
    // orphanRemoval = Do you want to delete orphaned children?
  )
  @JoinColumn(name = "someField",
    unique = false,
    updateable = false,
    insertable = false)
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
public class Child {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int someField;

}
```

This is a uni-directional mapping, but you could add the "parent" association to the child if you like. Then you have to add methods to make sure they are synchronized ([see here])[4](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

If they are not unique and there is no foreign key, I'm not sure this will work. But in that case, you could use [`@JoinFormula`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-jpa-manytoone-relationship-to-a-sql-query-using-the-hibernate-joinformula-annotation/) to provide an SQL query to join against.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify some of the points. When I used `@OneToMany` hibernate generated a unique key constraint on the parent side which is not correct (for my use case). That's why I used the `@ManyToMany` annotation. My current workaround is an AspectJ advice which just loads the list when loading the Foo/Parent entity but this feels very wrong.

Comment: But ManyToMany is for when A has a collection of Bs and B has a collection of A. You seem to have a 1-to-n not n-to-n relation. Also, what do you mean "generates" a unique key constraint: if you use an existing Schema, why do you use Hibernate Schema generation (DDL auto).

Comment: I've updated my question setting the properties on the JoinColumn, like unique=false, etc. With the "update/insertable = false" it will not touch that column

Comment: 1. Perhaps I got the relation concept wrong. My understanding of an 1-to-n is that it implies uniqueness on the join column of the left side which I don't have. Hibernating generating a unique key constraint encouraged me in this interpretation.
2. I generate the scheme to see the different effects of the approaches I tried. I don't want to have a solution which requires me to manually create the scheme first or just "coincidentally" work with the current scheme.